# return true or false based on button clicked in pop up window

Tags: javascript, callback, form-submit

Okay so with jQuery I've intercepted the .submit() of a form and I want to create a custom pop up window that shows them the data that the entered and asks them to confirm it. If they click the confirm button true is returned to .submit() and they continue but if false is pressed then they should not move on and have a chance to change their entry.

I already have the pop up window being made fine with the contents of the form being displayed and the buttons being shown. What I'm not sure how to do is bind the click functions of the buttons so that if one is clicked it returns false to .submit() and if the other is clicked true is returned to .submit()

If you need me to post some of my code just let me know.

I don't want to use a confirm dialogue since i would like it to be a custom pop up window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to pass the .submit() as a callback function to the dialogue. This isn't a one line solution but rather a pattern that you should get familiar with. This http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQVTIJBZook will probably be helpful for some of this topic along with other common issues that you may come across

Example:

```
function openPopup(form) {
    //
    // Put whatever code you use to open you
    // popup here
    //

    // Bind click handler to submit form if they click confim
    $("#id_of_confim_button").on("click", function() {
        // Get the form that was
        form.submit();
    });

    // Bind click handler for cancel button
    $("#id_of_cancel_button").on("click", function() {
        //
        // Code to close your popup
        //
    });
};

$("#id_of_form_submit_button").on("click", function(event) {
    // Stops the form from submitting
    event.preventDefault();

    // Get the form you want to submit
    var form = $("#form_being_submit");

    // Call your 'open custom popup' function and pass
    // the form that should be submitted as an argument
    openPopup(form);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `confirm()` dialogue:

```
var submit = confirm('Are you sure?');

if (submit) {
    $(this).submit();
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

This works by the dialogue presenting the message `"Are you sure?"` to the user, if the user clicks on the confirmation `ok` button, the dialogue returns `true` to the variable `submit`, otherwise it returns `false`.

If `false` is returned (the user clicked `cancel`), then the `if` evaluates to `false`, and the `else` is executed.

Comment: but i don't want to use a confirm dialogue, they are pretty ugly

Comment: well i did say using my own custom popup window

Answer (score 0):

Catching only this form's submits' `click` event won't handle all cases (f.ex. if someone hits enter on a non-textarea input, the form submits too).

If i want to handle submit in an asynchronous way, i used to fire manually `submit` after the original was prevented & bring in an `isDirty` state:

```
(function () {
  var isDirty = true;
  $("form#id").on("submit", function ( evt ) {
    if (isDirty) {
      evt.preventDefault();
      popup( "... params ...", function () {
        // this will called, when the popup ensures the form can be submitted
        // ... & it will be called by the popup
        isDirty = false;
        $("form#id").submit();
      } );
    }
  });
})();
```